# Running SSIS Package in scheduled job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to run SSIS package stored on my local PC through SQL Server Agent job , and it always fails.

When run through my Login, it's always success.

Below is the error I get:

> Executed as user: DESKTOP\sa. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package
>   Utility  Version 10.50.6000.34 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:45:56 AM 
>   Error: 2018-10-03 10:45:56.69     Code: 0xC0011007     Source:
>   {BE221908-99A4-4707-8287-0B5FEE969825}      Description: Unable to
>   load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML
>   format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End Error  Error:
>   2018-10-03 10:45:56.69     Code: 0xC0011002     Source:
>   {BE221908-99A4-4707-8287-0B5FEE969825}      Description: Failed to
>   open package file "H:\SSIS\ssPackage.dtsx" due to error 0x80070003
>   "The system cannot find the path specified.".  This happens when
>   loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly
>   into the XML document. This can be the result of either providing an
>   incorrect file name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML
>   file was specified and has an incorrect format.  End Error  Could not
>   load package  because of error 0xC0011002.  Description: Failed to
>   open package file due to error 0x80070003 "The system cannot find the
>   path specified.".  This happens when loading a package and the file
>   cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can
>   be the result of either providing an incorrect file name was specified
>   when calling LoadPackage or the XML file was specified and has an
>   incorrect format.  Source: {BE221908-99A4-4707-8287-0B5FEE969825} 
>   Started:  10:45:56 AM  Finished: 10:45:56 AM  Elapsed:  0.016 seconds.
>   The package could not be found.  The step failed.

Please help.

I'm using 64-bit operating system.

Thank you!

Sindhu

Comment: Connection string issues, that is  due to permission issue. How are you running ssis package as `file system or ssis catalogue or sql server` ?

Comment: Im running it through FILE SYSTEM.

Comment: Create a Proxy account and add your credentials to that account. When you schedule job, use that proxy account. It shouldn't throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Its permissions issue.Although, your domain account or sql account have permissions to access file share. SQL services could be running under local admin account which doesn't have permissions to that file share.
Workaround for this issue :

Create a Proxy account and run that package with that account

Create Credential

1) Right click on credentials, add you account name in identity 
                      ( because your account 
                          have access to the folder share)

[image]

Step2: Create a Proxy account , add  credential you have created earlier

[image]

Step3:

Finally select proxy name from drop down to schedule SQL AGENT job

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Important bit from the error

> Description: Failed to open package file "H:\SSIS\ssPackage.dtsx" due
>   to error 0x80070003 "The system cannot find the path specified.".

A permissions issue to the file. Check that the user executing the Agent Job has access to the folder and file location

Comment: May i know how to give permission to access the folder ??